# How to change the size of the name of a node, in a tikzpicture

Tags: fontsize, nodes, tikzpagenodes

This is my code, in this code, the names of the nodes appeared very small, How could I modified this size?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\title{Ecuaciones}
\author{Universidad Nacional de Colombia\\Sede Manizales\\ \\Alumnos:\\Juan Pablo     Muñoz Diaz\\Carlos Fernando Ospina Trujillo\\ }
\begin{document}
\maketitle

%Primera ecuacion
\textbf{Primera ecuacion}



%%
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.266666666667,0.266666666667,0.266666666667}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}

\resizebox{5cm}{5cm}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-12.6261679156,0.561231972758) rectangle (-1.10615793659,11.8708308106);
\fill[color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.1] (-11.6117166802,1.30462670705) --         (-1.61171668024,1.30462670705) -- (-1.61171668024,11.3046267071) --         (-11.6117166802,11.3046267071) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=4.pt] (0.997953475103,10.0297333254) -- (11.5185105336,10.0297333254);
\draw (-11.6117166802,1.30462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (-11.6117166802,1.30462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (-1.61171668024,1.30462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,11.3046267071);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (-1.61171668024,11.3046267071)-- (-11.6117166802,11.3046267071);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (-11.6117166802,11.3046267071)-- (-11.6117166802,1.30462670705);
\draw (-6.61171668024,11.3046267071)-- (-6.61171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw (-9.11171668024,11.3046267071)-- (-9.11171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw (-4.11171668024,11.3046267071)-- (-4.11171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw (-11.6117166802,8.80462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,8.80462670705);
\draw (-11.6117166802,6.30462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,6.30462670705);
\draw (-11.6117166802,3.80462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,3.80462670705);
\draw (-6.36643646582,7.71521077251) node[anchor=north west,minimum size=10pt]     {$u_{2}$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (11.5185105336,10.0297333254) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (11.9919356012,11.2395973871) node {$lado = 10$};
\draw[color=black] (-6.47164203641,0.929451469805) node {$h$};
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (-6.61171668024,8.80462670705) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (-6.15602532465,9.71411661362) node {$u_{6}$};
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (-6.61171668024,3.80462670705) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (-6.05081975407,4.71685201085) node {$u_{14}$};
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (-9.11171668024,6.30462670705) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (-8.62835623339,7.18918291959) node {$u_{1}$};
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (-4.11171668024,6.30462670705) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (-3.63109163062,7.18918291959) node {$u_{3}$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not compile for me, so I can't test it, but perhaps try removing `\begin{scriptsize}` and `\end{scriptsize}`. Also, you are applying `\resizebox` which will resize the graphics and the text.

Comment: I have already corrected the code @PeterGrill so I hope I will be able to receive your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\resizebox` will scale both the graphics and the text. It would be better if you just applied a `scale` to the `tikzpicture` instead:

[image]

### Notes:

- I commented out the stuff that was irrelvant to this question.
- I also commented out the `\begin{scriptsize}` and `\end{scriptsize}`, as that was also resulting the changes in font size of the text. Am not sure if that is desired or not.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\pagestyle{empty}
%
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{float}
%
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%\title{Ecuaciones}
%\author{Universidad Nacional de Colombia\\Sede Manizales\\ \\Alumnos:\\Juan Pablo     Muñoz Diaz\\Carlos Fernando Ospina Trujillo\\ }
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
%
%%Primera ecuacion
%\textbf{Primera ecuacion}
%
%
%
%%
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.266666666667,0.266666666667,0.266666666667}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}

%\resizebox{5cm}{5cm}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]%[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-12.6261679156,0.561231972758) rectangle (-1.10615793659,11.8708308106);
\fill[color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.1] (-11.6117166802,1.30462670705) --         (-1.61171668024,1.30462670705) -- (-1.61171668024,11.3046267071) --         (-11.6117166802,11.3046267071) -- cycle;
\draw[line width=4.pt] (0.997953475103,10.0297333254) -- (11.5185105336,10.0297333254);
\draw (-11.6117166802,1.30462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (-11.6117166802,1.30462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (-1.61171668024,1.30462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,11.3046267071);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (-1.61171668024,11.3046267071)-- (-11.6117166802,11.3046267071);
\draw [color=zzttqq] (-11.6117166802,11.3046267071)-- (-11.6117166802,1.30462670705);
\draw (-6.61171668024,11.3046267071)-- (-6.61171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw (-9.11171668024,11.3046267071)-- (-9.11171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw (-4.11171668024,11.3046267071)-- (-4.11171668024,1.30462670705);
\draw (-11.6117166802,8.80462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,8.80462670705);
\draw (-11.6117166802,6.30462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,6.30462670705);
\draw (-11.6117166802,3.80462670705)-- (-1.61171668024,3.80462670705);
\draw (-6.36643646582,7.71521077251) node[anchor=north west,minimum size=10pt]     {$u_{2}$};
%\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (11.5185105336,10.0297333254) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (11.9919356012,11.2395973871) node {$lado = 10$};
\draw[color=black] (-6.47164203641,0.929451469805) node {$h$};
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (-6.61171668024,8.80462670705) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (-6.15602532465,9.71411661362) node {$u_{6}$};
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (-6.61171668024,3.80462670705) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (-6.05081975407,4.71685201085) node {$u_{14}$};
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (-9.11171668024,6.30462670705) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (-8.62835623339,7.18918291959) node {$u_{1}$};
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (-4.11171668024,6.30462670705) circle (5.5pt);
\draw[color=uuuuuu] (-3.63109163062,7.18918291959) node {$u_{3}$};
%\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}%}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you have exported this code from some drawing software, hence it is not readable enough. On the other hand, for such simple diagrams, you can write the code yourself. Here is one sample:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.266666666667,0.266666666667,0.266666666667}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[zzttqq,fill opacity=0.1] 
            (-0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth) rectangle ([shift={(0.5\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)}]4,4);
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3} {
        \draw (\x,0) -- (\x,4);
    }
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3} {
        \draw (0,\y) -- (4,\y);
    }
    \foreach \x/\y/\a in {2/-0.2/h,2.3/1.4/u_{14},2.3/2.4/u_{2},2.3/3.4/u_{6},1.3/2.4/u_{1},3.3/2.4/u_{3}} {
        \node[font=\small] at (\x,\y){$\a$};
    }
    \foreach \x/\y in {1/2,2/1,2/3,3/2} {
        \draw[fill=uuuuuu] (\x,\y) circle(1.5pt);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder @HarishKumar: why do you say that it is much simpler to write the code by myself i thing it is too mucho simpler to draw it and copy and paste the code, however I would really love to learn how to develop such codes, becouse I imagine you did'nt take more time than I taked drawing it in "Geogebra"(Drawing Sofware), If you have some advices to learn to write those codes i would really apreciatted.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz While coding yourself, you have the full control on things and you see the difference between your code and mine (readability wise). And to learn there is beautiful manual (`texdoc pgfmanual` from terminal) and practice goes a long way. Read the manual, try to code and ask here when you are stuck.